# Can't delete an object in IndexedDB with auto_increment key

Tags: object, key, auto-increment, indexeddb

I can really use some help on my code.
I'm using IndexedDB in my web app, and I've created two objectStore : 
             - companyToCall
             - companyCalled

Both contain Company objects (custom class in js I've made).
Here goes the schema :

```
databaseOpeningRequest.onupgradeneeded = function(event) 
{
    db = event.target.result;
    db.createObjectStore('companyToCall', { autoIncrement: true }).createIndex("id", "id", { unique: true});
    db.createObjectStore('companyCalled', { autoIncrement: true }).createIndex("id", "id", { unique: true});
 }
```

I've decided to not use Company.id as a key in the DB because I wanted to memorize the order of insertion in database, for instance you insert subsequently companies with id 25 20 and 30 in the db, I want their keys to be like this : company 25 -> 1 / company 20 -> 2 / company 30 -> 3

All those companies are first inserted in the CompanyToCall Storage and when I'm done working with one I want to put it in the CompanyCalled storage and delete it from the CompanyToCall Storage.

Unfortunately, the deletion in the CompanyToCall storage won't work and I can't figure out why.
Here is the deletion :

```
var removeCompanyFromToCallStorage = function(company)
{
    if (activateLocalStorage)
    {
        var requete = db.transaction(['companyToCall'], 'readwrite').objectStore('companyToCall').delete(company.getId());
        requete.onsuccess = function(e)
        {
            console.log('worked');
        };
    }
};
```

I got the "worked" on my console but when I'm checking my db I can still see this company in the wrong storage (after refreshing etc etc)

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to specify a keypath when creating your object stores in order to reference objects by an id. A keypath is like the primary key of a record in an ordinary relational table. Using a keypath is optional. You currently have no primary key defined, so doing a delete-by-primary-key operation, without specifying which field in the object represents the primary key, does not make sense. You can define a keypath by changing `db.createObjectStore('companyToCall', { autoIncrement: true })...` to  `db.createObjectStore('companyToCall', {keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true})...`. See [IDBDatabase.createObjectStore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBDatabase.createObjectStore) for additional information.

Second, [IDBObjectStore.prototype.delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore.delete) fires a success event regardless of whether an object within the object store was modified. Many operations in indexedDB fire success events regardless of what actually happened. Basically success just means that you properly requested the operation to be performed and that the operation completed. It does not mean the operation did something. This is why 'worked' is always displayed in your console. Unfortunately, there is no simple way to detect whether the object was actually deleted. Instead of 'worked', you can only print something like 'successfully requested object to be deleted', but you will never know if the request actually did anything unless you create a later get request to check it.